# How do we know Newton's law of universal gravitation is correct?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

As far as I imagine, gravitational constant $G$ is an experimented value.

Assuming $G$ is exact with no error, how do we know that the force is inversly proportinal to $r^2$ not something like $r^{1.999999}$ ?

Is it related to the fact that we are living in 3-dimensional space, or is it experimented too?

Comment: *How do we know Newton's law universal gravitation is correct?* We know it *isn't*, in general. We have a better theory of gravity which doesn't involve the inverse square law and lives in $4$ dimensions. The other fundamental inverse-square law, Coulomb's, also fails in a certain regime and we have a better theory for that too. In the regime of their validity though, you are right as pointed out in the answers.

Comment: FWIW, G is *really* hard to measure precisely, which is why we only know it to 6 significant figures. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant#Value_and_uncertainty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed related to the fact that we live in a 3d space. The surface of a sphere varies with $r^2$. This means that the force varies with $r^{-2}$. If the surface gets twice as big, for, example, the field distributed over this surface is distributed over a four times as big surface. This means that the force is 4 times as small. *Exactly* four times ($r^2$ times).
This assumes that the world lives in a Euclidean, "straight" space. It also assumes that the force extends to infinity.
In the theory of general relativity, the world is not-Euclidean and the relation with $r$ is not *exactly* an $r^2$-like one, but *almost* (in some cases, like the space surrounding a black hole, the relation is *far* from the $r^2$-like form if you're close to the hole and if the mass of the hole is relatively small). But general relativity is not what to consider in the world of Newton. I just mentioned it to be a bit more precise.
So in the world of Newton, it's indeed because we are living in a three-dimensional space. We don't have to measure it in advance and the measurements that *are* done do indeed confirm the theory. It *could* of course be the case that the force varies in a different manner (like the strong nuclear force). But luckily it's not.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse r-squared dependence is a consequence of living in 3 dimensions of space with gravity. This dependence has been experimentally tested and accounts extremely well for the motions of things which vary in size from bowling balls to stars.

By the way, we have known for decades that newtonian gravity yields the *wrong answers* when applied to extremely heavy objects and things moving at extremely high speeds. This means we already know it is not *universal*, but is instead a completely useful and accurate *approximation* for "weak" fields.

Answer (score 1):

$F_G\propto1/r^2$ is indeed linked to the three spatial dimensions of our universe. You might think of it like this: As you get farther away from the object which exerts the gravitational force on you, this force is "spread" over a larger area. This area is the surface of a sphere with your distance $r$ as radius.

Since we know<sup>1</sup> that the surface area of a sphere is $A=4\pi r^2$, it follows that the gravitational force is proportional to $r^2$ – or rather *inversely* proportional to $r^2$, i.e. proportional to $1/r^2$ since gravity gets weaker with increasing distance.

This is similar (if not identical) to light intensity being $\propto1/r^2$: The photons spread over a larger area as distance grows which can be nicely visualized:

[image]
<sup>([Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Inverse_square_law.svg))</sup>

For gravity, we don't have a "force particle"<sup>2</sup> which is spread out more, but the principle is the same.

> How do we know Newton's law of universal gravitation is correct?

By experiments. However, as you might know, Newtonian gravity fails to make accurate predictions for extremely heavy objects such as stars or black holes. This is where General Relativity comes into play. So, you could say that Newtonian gravity is "wrong".

---

<sup>1</sup> 3blue1brown has made a video explaining why $A=4\pi r^2$: [But why is a sphere's surface area four times its shadow?](https://youtu.be/GNcFjFmqEc8)

<sup>2</sup> At least, none has been found so far. A quantum theory of gravity would have a [graviton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton).